# Setting the new pixel values

Tags: java, image, rgb

I have the following code to get the pixel values of RGB

```
BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/MyDell/workspace/Chaotic/bear.jpg"));      
int[] pixel;
for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {
for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
    pixel = bi.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, new int[3]);
    System.out.println(pixel[0] + " - " + pixel[1] + " - " + pixel[2] + " - "(bi.getWidth() * y + x));      
      }
}
```

How can i change the pixel values of RGB to new values?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to *achieve,* and why not use Java-2D to achieve it?

Comment: I want to xor the rgb values with some integer value and write it a image.

Comment: I am Xoring the rgb values with a number generated from chaotic sequence generator to encrypt the image. later i xor the same number with the encrypted image so to get back the original image.

Answer (score 1):

You can set individual pixels on a `BufferedImage img` as follows:

```
int r = // red component 0...255
int g = // green component 0...255
int b = // blue component 0...255
int col = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
img.setRGB(x, y, col);
```

Check out [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/graphics/bufferedimage_setrgb.shtml) for more info.